# What are these female connectors called?

Tags: valves, schrader

I need help finding out what these female connectors/attachments are called so that I can buy them for my air tank project. Basically these are found on those portable air compressors which connect to schrader valves by screwing them on. I don't want those quick connect head types, just the regular screw on types where the knurled part rotates freely without rotating the hose attached to it. The hose I will be using is the 1/4" compressor hose and the valve I have is the generic tubeless tyre schrader valve.

I initially thought these were called barb connectors but I found out they don't have that push pin inside them which releases the air once the connector is tightened to the schrader valve.

Here are some images

[image]

I reckon something that looks like this is preferred since it's easier to attach to my hose without any crimping.

[image]

Comment: At a guess, I'd call them a female schrader-valve connector, but that's likely not their real name.

Comment: @Criggie Yes I tried that but no luck

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"THREAD-ON SCHRADER CHUCK" yields good search results

[image]

Comment: FYI, *chuck* is the term for a pump head. I think most Presta chucks are clamp on, but screw-on Presta chucks should exist (e.g. Lezyne pumps). I'm not as familiar with Schrader arrangements.

Comment: Yes, I think this is the thing, although it's a bit hard to come by.

Answer (score -4):

The other answer noted what they are called, but I'll provide some reasons for why not to use them.

Firstly, the Schrader valve or the connector threads may be made from brass or other weak material. Cross-thread and you can ruin not only the valve but also the connector. Usually the threads are only made to accept a valve cap which is very light plastic part (and if you cross-thread the valve cap you only damage the valve cap threads not the valve threads). Once ruined, the connection will not work. A quick connector would work also on a valve with ruined threads.

Secondly, if there is nothing to push the Schrader pin, you will require a large overpressure to be enough to push the spring when inflating. However, these connectors are also available with a feature to push the Schrader pin.

Thirdly, they fail to work on Schrader valves that have non-standard valve cap threads.

Fourthly, they are slower to use than the quick connectors.

Fifthly, because they are slower to use, if there is a feature to push the Schrader pin, when you unscrew, you lose more pressure than you would lose with quick connectors. Also when screwing in, you lose a lot of pressure so you don't get accurate information on what the pressure in the tire was.

Comment: A threaded interface is completely normal, if not even required for good function, on shock pumps. Works completely fine for high pressures and low volumes. You lose LESS air with them, not more. That's exactly why they are used for shock pumps.

Comment: @juhist I don't know why your answer got so many downvotes but here are my thoughts. I don't mind if it takes a couple of more seconds to attach this to the valve and also from my personal experience I've found this connector to lose less air than the quick connector while removing them.

Comment: @VladimirF I've been using portable air pumps for a very long time and just like you said I didn't find any problems with the thread and also I found it loses less air than the quick connectors. And even if the threads on the schrader valve is damaged, a replacement tubeless valve is a dime a dozen and very easy to install (for air tank).

Comment: This does not appear to even attempt to answer the question, but rather raises a new question and answers that instead.

Comment: @Kokachi likely because your question was well-defined and specific "what is this called" while this goes off onto tangents, which while interesting and related still don't answer the original question.  Could tweak the scope of this question or ideally ask a new question of "what's the advantage/disadvantage with using threaded schrader chucks over a quick fitting chuck?"

Comment: @Criggie I see your point.